# Using time manager for shapefile with different timestamps

Tags: qgis, animation, timemanager

I have a network which contains speed information for each segment at different timestamps. I would like to create an animation of speed changes during the day. There is multiple columns which contain speed for a segment at a given time. How do I work around the fact that time manager plugin only reads time value from one column ?

Comment: you probably need to modify your data to have only one column for the timestamp. to get really useful answers you should  give more detail on your data structure and/or post an extract of your data